# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, jzmq

I have a java application using an external dll (zmq). When I run it in debug mode in Eclipse it's all fine. However, when I export the application as Runnable JAR file then trying to run it, I'm getting that error referencing the dll.
Following my research on this site I configured the build path for JRE System Library, added that path of the folder containing the dll to Native library location, but I'm still getting that error.
Is there anything I need to do further? Or different?
Thanks.

Comment: so this external jar exist in the runnabble jar ?

Comment: It's not external jar; it's external dll.

Comment: ohkk whatever file,so it exist in runnable jar ?

Comment: Should be. In the Export settings I selected "Package required libraries into generated jar". I also tried to select "Extract required libraries into generated JAR". Got the same error in both cases.

Comment: U can open the jar and check whatever files/classes exist in it.Mat b ur jar is not getting created properly

Comment: How do I do that (open the jar to check its content)?

Comment: open it using winrar or any decompiler

Answer (score 3):

JZMQ needs two things to run: `zmq.dll` (the native ZMQ library) and `jzmq.dll` (the "bridge" library between Java and ZMQ). The particular error you are getting means your compile environment can't locate `jzmq.dll`; you just need to specify the path where it can find `jzmq.dll`. Note that, as far as I'm aware, there is no way for `jzmq.dll` to be in a JAR file so you can just include it in your classpath.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you exactly how to do it in Windows. I come from Linux, where DLLs are SO files. There it would be a simple `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/jzmq`.